# I am trying to design a chrome extension which should read a Recors.json file and and should fill that data in currently opened specific form

Tags: javascript

Either my 1 module is not working with any reason (don't know what is it) or my fetching process of data from json file is not working I don't know. Help me out to do this.

I have created a background.js file which should read the data from json file and send it to another file where it is going to use.
I have created another file named context.js file which is going to access the specific page to render the data from json file(I think not working properly).

```
background.js file

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  if (port.name === "formData") {
    const url = port.sender.url;
    let filePath;

    if (url.includes("https://www.police.rajasthan.gov.in/*")) {
      filePath = "Records.json";
    }else {
      console.log("Error: Unknown URL");
      return;
    }

    fetch(filePath)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((formData) => {
        port.postMessage(formData);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error in fetching the data:", error);
      });
  }
});

Content.js file
// Connect to the background script
const port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "formData" });

// Send a message to request form data
port.postMessage({ action: "getFormData" });

// Listen for messages from the background script
port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
  if (message.formData) {
    const ServentUploadForm = document.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlvisible");
    const ServentID = ServentUploadForm.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSIDNo");
    const ServentFName = ServentUploadForm.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSFirstName");
    const ServentLName = ServentUploadForm.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSLastName");
    const ServentFFName = ServentUploadForm.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSFirstFName");
    const ServentFLName = ServentUploadForm.querySelector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtSLastFName");
    const firstRecord = message.formData[0];
    ServentID.value = firstRecord.id;
    ServentFName.value = firstRecord.SFName;
    ServentLName.value = firstRecord.SLName;
    ServentFFName.value = firstRecord.FFName;
    ServentFLName.value = firstRecord.FLName;
  } else {
    console.log("Error in loading the data");
  }
});
```

Comment: Actually, `*` is allowed but I doubt that, that is the URL you're looking for.

Comment: If you want to try with full URL then here it is "https://www.police.rajasthan.gov.in/verificationform.aspx"